# Why is constexpr assuming my method to be const?

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr, member-functions

Writing a primitive type wrapper, I got this error from the compiler:

```
struct Integer
{
    constexpr Integer( int i )
        : m_i( i )
    { }

    constexpr Integer& operator++( )
    {
        ++m_i;            // error: increment of member 'Integer::m_i' in read-only object
        return *this;     // error: binding 'const Integer' to reference of type 'Integer&' discards qualifiers
    }

    int m_i;
};

int main(int , char *[])
{
    Integer i = 0;
    ++i;
    ++i;
    ++i;
    return i.m_i;
}
```

The compiler is assuming that my `constexpr` method is a `const` method. Why is it so? Does it mean my wrappers will never have the same performances/optimization chances as a primitive type? I mean:

```
int main(int , char *[])
{
    int i = 0;
    ++i;
    ++i;
    ++i;
    return i;
}
```

Would this be optimized out compared to my code?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3598.html

Comment: @NathanOliver I can't believe they did not think about it back in C++11. I enabled C++14 and now it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, `constexpr` is a **stronger** form of `const`.

Comment: Note that this argumentation fails since C++14, where a `constexpr` method is not implicitly `const`.

Comment: And you can also have `constexpr const int foo`

Comment: @Rakete1111 Enabling C++14 instead of C++11 made indeed the code compile. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To improve performance use keyword **inline**.

**constexpr** makes your object immutable

Comment: Function defined inside class declaration, like in my example code, are already automatically inlined. But this does not mean that they are going to be evaluated at compile time, which is what I meant with my question.